# What does BASE_PATH of CONTENT_PROVIDER really means?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to build a Content_Provider but i'm stuck on Base_path....

For example I have table name arrival like below : [image]

How can I name a CONTENT_URI ?
Can anyone help me out ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#contentprovider_overview

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> A content `URI` is a `URI` that identifies data in a provider. Content URIs include the symbolic name of the entire provider (its authority)
>   and a name that points to a table (a path). When you call a client
>   method to access a table in a provider, the content URI for the table
>   is one of the arguments.
>
> In the preceding lines of code, the constant `CONTENT_URI` contains the content `URI` of the user dictionary's "words" table. The
>   ContentResolver object parses out the URI's authority, and uses it to
>   "resolve" the provider by comparing the authority to a system table of
>   known providers. The ContentResolver can then dispatch the query
>   arguments to the correct provider.
>
> The ContentProvider uses the path part of the content URI to choose the table to access. A provider usually has a path for each
>   table it exposes.
>
> In the previous lines of code, the full `URI` for the "words" table is:
>
> `content://user_dictionary/words`
>   where the `user_dictionary` string is the provider's authority, and words string is the table's path. The string content:// (the scheme)
>   is always present, and identifies this as a content `URI`.

So in a `content_uri`, you have an `authority` and a `base_path`. The `ContentResolver` will use the `authority` part to decide which provider to choose and then the `base_path` part to decide which table to provide the data from. So, simplifying, the `base_path` is usually the path for your particular table within your provider.

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) guide for more and go through [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) tutorial as well.